# TypeScript: Define a union type from an array of strings

Tags: typescript

I can't be the first person coming across this, but my searches have not turned up any useful leads yet. Would greatly appreciate some expert TypeScript advice.

Say I have an array:

```
const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"];
```

and I want to define an object mapping each fruit to some fun facts about it:

```
interface Facts {
    color: string,
    typicalWeight: number
}

const fruitFacts: { [key: members of fruits]: Facts } = {
    "Apple": { color: "green", typicalWeight: 150 }
    //
}
```

How do I do that `[key: members of fruits]` part?

Bonus: How do I enforce that my `fruitFacts` object exhaust all the keys derived from the array as well, so that it specifies facts for Apples, Oranges, and Pears in the example above.

Comment: Do you know the exact strings at compile time? If not, you cannot define such a type.

Comment: Let's say I do. Can I avoid duplicating them though? i.e. avoid doing `type FruitName = "Apple" | "Orange"; const fruitNames : FruitName[] = ["Apple", "Orange"];`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values/45257357

Answer (score 192, accepted):

TypeScript 3.4 added [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) which allow for writing this as:

```js
const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"] as const;
type Fruit = typeof fruits[number]; // "Apple" | "Orange" | "Pear"
```

With `as const` TypeScript infers the type of `fruits` above as `readonly["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]`. Previously, it would infer it as `string[]`, preventing `typeof fruits[number]` from producing the desired union type.

Comment: why doesn't this work?: `const fruitTypes = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"];`
`const fruits = fruitTypes as const;`

Comment: @techguy2000 I think it's because you could have:

`const fruitTypes = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]; fruitTypes.push("Kiwi"); const fruits = fruitTypes as const;`. TS has no reliable way of knowing in this case that the type should now be `["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Kiwi"];`, so it's an unsafe pattern to allow marking it as `const` later on after the initial definition.

Comment: It still doesn't work when I freeze the array: `const fruitTypes = Object.freeze(["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]);`  I really hope some variation of this will work...

Comment: @techguy2000 that might be worthwhile to open up as a feature suggestion in the TS issues tracker, it does seem like it could be reasonable to type this case as `readonly["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]` instead of `readonly string[]`.

Comment: This way doesn't allow to use `fruits.include(var)` for a type check:

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Apple" | "Orange" | "Pear"'.ts(2345)`

Comment: @TotalAMD, It does if the variable is properly typed or casted. See https://tsplay.dev/GNl8lN

Comment: why `fruits[number]` what does the number here mean?

Comment: @Batman writing `typeof fruits[number]` tells Typescript that what we are interested in is the type of the values stored within the `fruits` array. Because it's an Array, those values are indexed by `number`. In plain English, it's like we are asking TypeScript "for any given integer index requested from `fruits`, what are the possible types of the value that will be returned?"

Comment: why not this instead ? : ```type fruits = "Apple" | "Orange" | "Pear";```

Comment: @aestheticsData the idea here is to--without the need for repeating the list of elements--define both 1) a JavaScript array that is accessible at runtime 2) a matching type. If you define the type manually, you need to repeat the list of items like this: `type fruits = "Apple" | "Orange" | "Pear";  const fruits: fruits[] = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"];` (Not necessarily always the worst thing, sometimes being DRY is overrated!)

Comment: Bear in mind that `fruits` becomes readonly, so it will not be of type `Fruits[]`, and trying to use it as such results in an error like `The type 'readonly ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '("Apple" | "Orange" | "Pear")[]'.`. This reduces the situations where this array can actually be used so I'm not sure how useful a solution it is.

If there's a nice way to get both a union type, and an array of that type, without duplication I'd love to see it

Answer (score 28):

It can be done but first you need an extra function to help infer the string literal type for the array elements. By default Typescript will infer `string[]` for an array even if it is a constant. After we have an array of string literal types we can just use a type query to get the desired type

```
function stringLiteralArray<T extends string>(a: T[]) {
    return a;
}

const fruits = stringLiteralArray(["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]);
type Fruits = typeof fruits[number]
```

Since 3.4 you can also use a const type assertion instead of the `stringLiteralArray` function:

```
const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"] as const;
type Fruits = typeof fruits[number]
```

Comment: This specific callout for `typeof fruits[number]` was what I needed - it makes it a string union instead of a readonly string[]