# Create interface dynamically from JS object of properties and options

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to do the following in Typescript:

I have an object whose keys are properties and values are an array of the options for these properties:

```
const options = {
  foo: [fooOption1, fooOption2, ...],
  bar: [barOption1, barOption2, ...],
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to create an interface such that

```
interface example {
  foo: fooOption1 | fooOption2 | ...,
  bar: barOption1 | barOption2 | ...,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change your options object to a constant:

```
const options = {
  foo: ['fooOption1', 'fooOption2'],
  bar: ['barOption1', 'barOption2']
} as const;
```

Then, you can create desired interface by mapping each array to an union:

```
type OptionsInterface = {
    [K in keyof typeof options]: typeof options[K][number]
}


const xx: OptionsInterface = {
   foo: 'fooOption1',
   bar: 'barOptionError' // Expected error: 
                         // Type '"barOptionError"' is not assignable to type '"barOption1" | "barOption2"'.(2322)
}
```

See:

- [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)
- [TypeScript: Define a union type from an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085454/typescript-define-a-union-type-from-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very helpful! I thought you couldn't do this, but it seems it's only not possible for interfaces.