# Typescript define new type from array of strings with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an instance of my db user model and an array with a list of an object properties:

```
interface User = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  isActive: boolean,
  phone: string,
  // and a lot of other extra properties omitted here
}

const selectedFields = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
```

I'm trying to use typescript generics to build a new type with the original class and only the selected properties:

```
const selectedUserInterface = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
}
```

I know I can use "as const" like described here ( [TypeScript: Define a union type from an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085454/typescript-define-a-union-type-from-an-array-of-strings) )

```
const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"] as const;
type Fruit = typeof fruits[number]; // "Apple" | "Orange" | "Pear"
```

But what I want is to write a generic type, something like an utility type, that return the same without using "as const" and without repeating "typeof ....".

I tried this but it's not working:

```
type SelectProps<T extends object, K extends (keyof T) & string[]> = Pick<T, K>;
```

As a stepback (just to obtain literal type from array) I tried this, but can't understand why it's not working

```
type ArrayToUnion<T extends readonly any[]> = typeof T[number];
```

Can anyone explain and guide me to the solution?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://tsplay.dev/mAgk4w If so, then I will write up that answer. If not then a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help a lot here to understand what you want.

Comment: It works! But is there a way to avoid repeating "typeof" all the time, including it inside the generic type? (instead of writing type TestA = SelectProps<User, typeof selectedFields> I'd like to write type TestA = SelectProps<User, selectedFields> )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had your type right.

You had this:

```
K extends (keyof T) & string[]
```

Which means that `K` must be a `keyof T` and also a `string[]`. But what you actually want is that `K` must be a `(keyof T & string)[]`, that is an array where all members are a key of `T` and are also a `string`.

I think you want this:

```
type SelectProps<T, K extends readonly (keyof T)[]> = Pick<T, K[number]>;
```

You don't really need the `extends object`, or the `& string` here.

---

Now to make this work the type system must know what keys are provided. That means that this will not work:

```
const selectedFields = ['firstName', 'lastName'] // inferred as type: string[]
```

So you can `as const` there

```
const selectedFields = ['firstName', 'lastName'] as const
// inferred as type: readonly ['firstName', 'lastName']
```

Or you can use `satisfies`:

```
const selectedFields = ['firstName', 'lastName'] satisfies (keyof User)[]
// inferred as type: ('firstName' | 'lastName)[]
```

So now Typescript knows the prop names in the type system and can work with them.

---

> is there a way to avoid repeating "typeof" all the time.

A *value* is data your code can use at runtime. A *type* is a constraint that describe the structure of your values. You can't use a value as a type. And how you use the type of a value is with the `typeof` operator. So, no.

But you can declare it once and save it as a type alias:

```
const selectedFields = ['firstName', 'lastName'] satisfies (keyof User)[]
type UserSelectedFields = typeof selectedFields
```

---

Putting all that together it looks like this:

```
interface User {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  isActive: boolean,
  phone: string,
  // and a lot of other extra properties omitted here
}

const selectedFields = ['firstName', 'lastName'] satisfies (keyof User)[]
type UserSelectedFields = typeof selectedFields

type SelectProps<T extends object, K extends (keyof T)[]> = Pick<T, K[number]>;

type TestA = SelectProps<User, UserSelectedFields>
//   ^? { firstName: string, lastName: string }
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&jsx=0&ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnIzBTpgBycAthAFzKlSgDmANPsgDZykXV0PM2BYOgCCCMMAButZACMA9go4Q4IIcgAOACwUhZAkK3YB6E8jUATC5wVhkCmA7DasEAB5gocLVAWboSQh0B0pgMEhrVygIXABfXFwEPVJ6CBUJCEsAMWB0yxCAXmQAbQByIhJyKggylmQyrh4asoBdejhJdCJg5AAKAGsIAE9HNEwoAEoS1twwYYDx6ABldIhMnLyOAuRi+YCxzAzI3Pz0RP2UVeOABT9NdAAeABVkD0gQHYU5ACt1sHqAGk3p4IJ8QoMRmNntNWgA+XbIG7ABADF5AkogACulDk0HhAG4LgsUM9gmBRIjrv87v4nhhoPUGVBqRtTtt0HDcGYCMgAHoAfiAA)