# Enforce that an array is exhaustive over a union type

Tags: typescript

Given a strongly-typed tuple created using a technique such as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type):

```
const tuple = <T extends string[]>(...args: T) => args;
const furniture = tuple('chair', 'table', 'lamp');

// typeof furniture[number] === 'chair' | 'table' | 'lamp'
```

I want to assert at design time that it's exhaustive over another union type:

```
type Furniture = 'chair' | 'table' | 'lamp' | 'ottoman'
```

How can I create a type that will ensure that `furniture` contains each and only the types in the `Furniture` union?

The goal is to be able to create an array at design time like this, and have it fail should `Furniture` change; an ideal syntax might look like:

```
const furniture = tuple<Furniture>('chair', 'table', 'lamp')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really have direct support for an "exhaustive array".  You can guide the compiler into checking this, but it might be a bit messy for you.  A stumbling block is the absence of *partial type parameter inference* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)).  Here is my solution:

```
type Furniture = 'chair' | 'table' | 'lamp' | 'ottoman';

type AtLeastOne<T> = [T, ...T[]];

const exhaustiveStringTuple = <T extends string>() =>
  <L extends AtLeastOne<T>>(
    ...x: L extends any ? (
      Exclude<T, L[number]> extends never ? 
      L : 
      Exclude<T, L[number]>[]
    ) : never
  ) => x;


const missingFurniture = exhaustiveStringTuple<Furniture>()('chair', 'table', 'lamp');
// error, Argument of type '"chair"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"ottoman"'

const extraFurniture = exhaustiveStringTuple<Furniture>()(
  'chair', 'table', 'lamp', 'ottoman', 'bidet');
// error, "bidet" is not assignable to a parameter of type 'Furniture'

const furniture = exhaustiveStringTuple<Furniture>()('chair', 'table', 'lamp', 'ottoman');
// okay
```

As you can see, `exhaustiveStringTuple` is a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function, whose sole purpose is to take a manually specified type parameter `T` and then return a new function which takes arguments whose types are constrained by `T` but inferred by the call. (The currying could be eliminated if we had proper partial type parameter inference.)  In your case, `T` will be specified as `Furniture`.  If all you care about is `exhaustiveStringTuple<Furniture>()`, then you can use that instead:

```
const furnitureTuple =
  <L extends AtLeastOne<Furniture>>(
    ...x: L extends any ? (
      Exclude<Furniture, L[number]> extends never ? L : Exclude<Furniture, L[number]>[]
    ) : never
  ) => x;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgJwHYEtiOgXigcgMYAWAhigjlAD67BEBGANhOVTvUQLZjO4D2wwPdkSQ4A3AChxoSFACCwADIQiAZ2AB5JBAA8AFQB8UbAG1dAGigA6a7uMBdOxPF4eSNVAgAPYnDUoAbhAAysAIKEgA5rpwYIxGUHoensAQSAAmKlBqYZH6ABQAlEb64lAJCkkp6ZnySqoaWnr6+aVlVtaeAFxQFV5VGVDCIFAA-FB5rW1QAKKeePRwaTrmPcZIcOy0EAh2hn2pA1qBCKM9UN2z84vLFgprG1s7+vaTUEXdR9utRZiGnk4uNzAKDsFAqFThCLwZBoDDxLw+PyBEI5KIxRjaaGodAICD5Ap5fDEUg4Cw4GgMJhkticHAFCQAegZHgQCB4CAssgQEQ2qWBPAAZlBpNAcAAiQgkBBi8hgqBIPiDcEoCJIOhxARQMBEBAcCApE6C4XgUVivgCIRIGWSQHuPq6rGw3Hw7xEXzAALBUKQ6KxHSOnF4woTMpEqWk6jqqm4GlcMnmwTCCM4WgoJbAOmM5nbNkcqBi1PpsVQOUK4GqCGqqPCniDLU6vUGqBGkW4AMYHA21zuAWIbFw7AIt1Ir2o30Y9u4-GEyUkskUxjJ2PJhOWzPiJnNgDWRBAXaBUF7MMD46wrW0vWSBxqimUak0-r7TrxLSm1ksXTO+2qgyQwzGIZTDMcwLEsmJPoGtz3Js2y7JU17yhAxynBUFwgdc4HHhgUHrDBTwvFM7yIcc3zFFA-ySEAA)

Comment: This is pretty awesome. And I have to confess when I wrote this question I was absolutely trolling you because I'm a huge fan of your canon of TypeScript solutions on SO. So I just need to decide is the double-invocation worse than what I've been doing, e.g. `const furniture: { [key in Furniture]: true } = { chair: true, table: true, lamp: true };`. I think it's better; I care about order, and using a object where what I want is really an ordered set seems wrong, since then I have to (theoretically) worry about how consumers enumerate the keys.

Comment: Used your solution to define:
`type Status = 'draft' | 'signed' | 'withdrawn';
const statuses = exhaustiveTuple<Status>()('draft', 'signed', 'withdrawn');`
then immediately realized, i can do the opposite:
`const statuses = ['draft', 'signed', 'withdrawn'] as const;
type Status = typeof statuses[number];`. That way i don't have to type every string twice and the error message arising from exhaustiveTuple when something is missing is not very direct.

Answer (score 0):

I have other proposition

```js
type RemoveFirstFromTuple<T extends any[]> = 
  T extends [] ? undefined :
  (((...b: T) => void) extends (a: any, ...b: infer I) => void ? I : [])

const tuple = <T extends string[]>(...args: T) => args;

type FurnitureUnion = 'chair' | 'table' | 'lamp';
type FurnitureTuple = ['chair', 'table' , 'lamp'];

type Check<Union, Tuple extends Array<any>> = {
  "error": never,
  "next": Check<Union, RemoveFirstFromTuple<Tuple>>,
  "exit": true,
}[Tuple extends [] ? "exit" : Tuple[0] extends Union ? "next" : "error"];

type R = Check<FurnitureUnion, FurnitureTuple>; // true
type R1 = Check<'chair' | 'lamp' | 'table', FurnitureTuple>; // true
type R2 = Check<'chair' | 'lamp' | 'table', ['chair', 'table' , 'lamp', 'error']>; // nerver
```

Remove from tuple takes tuple and return tuple without first element (will be needed later)

Check will iterate on Tuple. Each step can return `never` when Tuple[0] don't extend Union, exit when input tuple is empty and next when Tuple[0] extends Union. In next step we recursive call Check but first we remove first element from Tuple by previous util

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20RemoveFirstFromTuple%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20%5B%5D%20%3F%20undefined%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20(((...b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20extends%20(a%3A%20any%2C%20...b%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20%5B%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20tuple%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20string%5B%5D%3E(...args%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20args%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FurnitureUnion%20%3D%20'chair'%20%7C%20'table'%20%7C%20'lamp'%3B%0D%0Atype%20FurnitureTuple%20%3D%20%5B'chair'%2C%20'table'%20%2C%20'lamp'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Check%3CUnion%2C%20Tuple%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22error%22%3A%20never%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22next%22%3A%20Check%3CUnion%2C%20RemoveFirstFromTuple%3CTuple%3E%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22exit%22%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%7D%5BTuple%20extends%20%5B%5D%20%3F%20%22exit%22%20%3A%20Tuple%5B0%5D%20extends%20Union%20%3F%20%22next%22%20%3A%20%22error%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20R%20%3D%20Check%3CFurnitureUnion%2C%20FurnitureTuple%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20R1%20%3D%20Check%3C'chair'%20%7C%20'lamp'%20%7C%20'table'%2C%20FurnitureTuple%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20R2%20%3D%20Check%3C'chair'%20%7C%20'lamp'%20%7C%20'table'%2C%20%5B'chair'%2C%20'table'%20%2C%20'lamp'%2C%20'error'%5D%3E%3B)

Comment: Just FYI it does not work under strict. I would not recommend using recusive type aliases like this, I believe it is actively discouraged and might not work in the future.

Comment: I agree that is not readable solution. Thanks for tip with strict mode, i fix it not it works. I'm not sure about future of TS. On microsoft roadmap there is no mentions about breaking changes.

Comment: @jcalz thanks to the PR pointed out by [your comment here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-674465012) does this now mean that this kind of recursive type-aliasing is now okay? Because it seems quite clever to me