# Typescript: Is it possible to type an array to include every key of an enum

Tags: arrays, typescript, enums

Is it possible to type the enum array in a way that forces it to contain every single value of the EPostFromField  enum?

This is a mongodb schema, and the use case would be to future proof the enum field if more enums are added later on (ie: have the compiler throw an error because the array doesn't have all the enum values enumerated).

As a bonus I guess the next level would be a solution that also guarantees that the enum array values are unique :)

```
export const enum EPostFromField {
  Resident = 'resident',
  AdminUser = 'admin-user', // Admin <user name>
  BoardUser = 'board-user', // Board <user name>
  AdminSociety = 'admin-society', // Admin <community name>
  BoardSociety = 'board-society', // Board <community name>
}

showPostAs: {
    type: String,
    default: EPostFromField.Resident,
    enum: [
      EPostFromField.Resident,
      EPostFromField.AdminUser,
      EPostFromField.BoardUser,
      EPostFromField.AdminSociety,
      EPostFromField.BoardSociety,
    ] as EPostFromField[], // DEVNOTE: Improve typing to enforce *every* unique key of enum
  },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enforce that an array is exhaustive over a union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265679/enforce-that-an-array-is-exhaustive-over-a-union-type)

Comment: enum objects, like all objects, have *keys* and *values* which are different.  `"Resident"` is a *key*, but `EPostFromFileld.Resident` is its *value*.  You talk about wanting to guarantee unique *keys*, but you are making an array of *values*.  Are you using the word "key" when you mean "value"?  If not, I'm confused; could you elaborate?

Comment: @jcalz Yes. Sorry for mixup. The end goal is to have the mongodb enum field contain (and therefore only accept) values of enum EPostFromField.  Thank you and I will edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) and do the following:

```
enum EPostFromField {
    Resident = "Resident",
    AdminUser = "AdminUser",
    BoardUser = "BoardUser",
    AdminSociety = "AdminSociety",
    BoardSociety = "BoardSociety"
}

const epostFromFieldKeys = Object.keys(EPostFromField);

const epostFromFields = epostFromFieldKeys as EPostFromField[]
```

You can see this running in this [playground link](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogCgewM4BcBiAnBE0EtgA2AJlAN4BQUVUASsErkaClALxQBEdDTIKHAGkrUAgkQi4QAVSTAMbTmInTZGQcKoAhBAEMMRGXIUdteg6vXUoSyQGUEAY3woAnsZsh7T4K8vVT+l7ObuwmuoGOwRzkAL7k5A4IIKhQwAAOyOhYOPjEANLALkgKAPIARgBWwA4oAHQA1oVIABTwmZjYeIREAJQA3PGJySzp7dldxMUKo6gdOd0FRVA6xW2z47lEANoAuoNJSAgEwLUECADmzTNZnZtIPUA).

The values in the array would be unique if you define the string values in the enum uniquely(!).

Comment: Thanks Ben! Yes, in effect this answers my question :) I was however searching for something a bit more condensed.

Take the typescript `Partial<T>` utility type, I was hoping for something more along these lines (but instead of a partial match, a complete + mandatory + unique match).