# TypeScript exhaustive array that contains all properties from a given enum

Tags: typescript, enums, unique, typescript-generics

I have an `enum` in TypeScript.

I want to write a function that returns an exhaustive array that contains exactly one reference to each property on the enum.

The return of the function will be an `Array<{ id: EnumValue, label: string }>`.

Sample code:

```
// I have this enum:
enum StepId {
  STEP_ONE = 'step-one-id',
  STEP_TWO = 'step-two-id',
}


// I want to define some function...
function someFunc() {
  return ...
}


// which returns an Array where every value from `StepId` is represented as an object with that value as the `id` field.
someFunc() === [
  { id: CustomStepIds.STEP_ONE, label: 'Step One', },
  { id: CustomStepIds.STEP_TWO, label: 'Step Two', },
];
```

I have tried to first solve the problem of enforcing all enum values are represented in an array. I've tried this:

```
enum CustomStepId {
  STEP_ONE = 'step-one-id',
  STEP_TWO = 'step-two-id',
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

const stepConfig: Array<{ id: ValueOf<typeof CustomStepId>, label: string }> = [
  { id: CustomStepId.STEP_ONE, label: 'Step One', },
  { id: CustomStepId.STEP_TWO, label: 'Step Two', },
  { id: CustomStepId.STEP_TWO, label: 'Step Two', }, // this should error, as STEP_TWO is already defined
];
```

However as noted in the comment above, while this enforces `id` is a `CustomStepId`, it does not enforce *uniqueness* of the field.

Comment: There is no native concept of "exhaustive/unique array" in TypeScript, so you'd have to build something manually.  How many members can we expect `StepId` to have?  If it's just a handful, then we can write an exhaustive array as a specific union of all possible accepted permutations of the members, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Ndv1dW).  But that doesn't scale well since the union grows superexponentially in the size of the enum.  If you've got even like eight or nine members then the [compiler will be unhappy](//tsplay.dev/N73aPN).  How would you like to proceed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enforce that an array is exhaustive over a union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265679/enforce-that-an-array-is-exhaustive-over-a-union-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following, on the basis that I (and much of the Typescript world) eschew Enums in favour of const arrays  [See typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXv58m)

I drafted mechanisms based on a map or a tuple, depending what you prefer or need.

```
type MemberOf<Arr extends readonly unknown[]> = Arr[number]

const STEP_IDS = ['step-one-id', 'step-two-id'] as const;
type StepId = MemberOf<typeof STEP_IDS>;

type StepConfigMap = {[k in StepId]: {
    label:string
}}

type ConfigTuple<Tuple extends readonly [...unknown[]]> = {
  [Index in keyof Tuple]: {
    id:Tuple[Index],
    label:string
  };
} & {length: Tuple['length']};

type StepConfigTuple = ConfigTuple<typeof STEP_IDS>;

const CONFIG_MAP: StepConfigMap  = {
    "step-one-id":{
        label:"something"
    },
    "step-two-id":{
        label:"something else"
    },
    // errors as it's already defined
    // An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.(1117)
    "step-two-id":{
        label:"something else"
    }
} as const;

const CONFIG_TUPLE = [
    {
        id:"step-one-id",
        label:"something",
    },
    {
        id:"step-two-id",
        label:"something",
    },
    // errors as it's already defined
    // Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 2.
    {
        id:"step-two-id",
        label:"something",
    }

] as const satisfies StepConfigTuple;
```

Comment: The key to this technique seems to be the `{ [k in StepId] : ... }` ([mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)) syntax. Seems to also work when `StepId` is an enum. What's the name of the `Arr[number]` construct you use in the `MemberOf` definition? I'm struggling to understand how it works.

Comment: Hopefully the example at https://tsplay.dev/wgBL0W will help. It shows how the use of as const to declare that the values inside a structure can't change, means that Typescript can reason about members and values and can use index syntax to resolve 'distributive' unions over e.g. number or object key. Therefore the result of Arr[number] is every value that can be indexed in Arr by any number (e.g. array members) and since they can't change, then Typescript can infer what those are.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, thanks a lot! (Thanks to it I found the `ArrayType[number]` syntax in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) as well.)