# TS: how to get constant Array element type

Tags: typescript

I'm using TS 3.4.5 with the const assertion. How can I retrieve the type of the elements of the declared constant array variable?

```
export type GetArrayElementType<T extends Array<any>> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;

export const MyConstArray = [
  'item1',
  'item2',
  'item3',
] as const;

export type MyConstArrayItem = GetArrayElementType<typeof MyConstArray>;
```

I'd like to have as output:

```
export type MyConstArrayItem = "item1" | "item2" | "item3"
```

I'm not totally sure how to extract the type information of the items because due to the const assertion, my array is not an array type anymore but is a constant tuple, so `GetArrayElementType` can't be applied on it.

Comment: Is that a typo or why do you have `item1` twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript array to string literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)
You even marked it yourself in the comment :D (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values/45257357#comment98860537_54399548)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use a conditional type you have to keep in mind that `as const` generates readonly arrays. So this should work as you expect it to:

```
export type GetArrayElementType<T extends readonly any[]> = T extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U : never;

export const MyConstArray = [
  'item1',
  'item2',
  'item3',
  'item4',
] as const;

export type MyConstArrayItem = GetArrayElementType<typeof MyConstArray>;
```

But the simpler solution is to not use a conditional type. Type index queries work better here:

```
export const MyConstArray = [
  'item1',
  'item2',
  'item3',
  'item4',
] as const;

export type MyConstArrayItem = typeof MyConstArray[number];
```

Answer (score 9):

Can be done easily with:

```
type MyConstArrayItem = typeof MyConstArray[number]
```

Comment: [Relevant github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20965)