# typescript array of specific string values

Tags: typescript

I have an array

```
const relations = ['profiles', 'locations', 'change_history']
```

If I want to create an interface like

```
interface IParams {
  id: number;
  relations: []string; // how to make this an array of those relations above?
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: how about `string[]` ? Or are you looking for something more specific ? like maybe `['profiles', 'locations', 'change_history']` itself

Comment: looking for something specific.  thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript array to string literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type)

Answer (score 32):

You basically have two options here:

**`const string enum`**

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums (for having the string values present for checks at runtime)
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums (to avoid some overhead concerning enums and replacing references to them in your code with the string literals)

You can define a const enum the following way:

```
const enum Relation {
  profiles = 'profiles', 
  locations = 'locations', 
  change_history = 'change_history'
}
```

**string literal types**

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types

```
type Relation = 'profiles' | 'locations' | 'change_history';
```

and like @guijob already pointed out this would be your interface (in both cases):

```
interface IParams {
  id: number;
  relations: Relation[];
}
```

Of course you could also inline this string literal type definition

```
relations: ('profiles' | 'locations' | 'change_history')[];
```

**But be aware that values are not checked at runtime!**

So if you add data from a resource that is not checked at compile time (like an API or user input) there is no guarantee for only those values being present.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [as const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to effortless type "relations"

```
const relations = ['profiles', 'locations', 'change_history'] as const

interface IParams {
  id: number;
  relations: typeof relations;
}
```

##### As an alternative, you can use `Array<T>`

```
interface IParams {
  id: number;
  relations: Array<'profiles' | 'locations' | 'change_history'>
}
```

##### Or if you prefer the other syntax

```
interface IParams {
  id: number;
  relations: ('profiles' | 'locations' | 'change_history')[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
enum Relation {
    profiles: 'profiles', locations: 'locations', change_history: 'change_history'
}

interface IParams {
  id: number;
  relations: Relation[];
}
```

Comment: The values at runtime will be numbers! https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html