# as const type name expected

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to implement [TypeScript array to string literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type)

I get a red underline error on PhpStorm with the error `type name expected` after `as const`

[image]

I also tried `<const>` but I get the same error near `<` and `>`

[image]

I user typescript 3.8.3

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

[image]

What IDE version do you use? TypeScript 3.4 non-widening literal contexts ('as const') is supported since 2019.2.1