# How to convert a type to a value

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type, for example:

```
type Contact = "email" | "phone"
```

Is there a way to convert the type `Contact` to a list of strings `["email", "phone"]`, so I could use that list at runtime, as an ordinary javascript value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript array to string literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't go from type to list, but you can go the other way around. You could do something like this:

```
const CONTACTS = ['email', 'phone'] as const
type Contact = typeof CONTACTS[number]
```

Then you can manage that list in only one place