# Best way to write type of Array I know

Tags: typescript

So I am importing file which contains the following values (and many other likes this)

```
export const COLUMN_TYPES = [
  "integer",
  "string",
  "boolean",
  "datetime",
  "image",
  "images",
  "text",
  "auth_key",
  "enum_type"
];
```

Now, I don't want the type of the above to be `Array<string>` since I am sure that it is only going to contain values.

If I don't write type and just import it gives following error

```
Cannot find module 'src/constants' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

What is the best way to fix this error? using `Array<string>` even though our array is constant with specific values? use enums?

Comment: What type do you want it to be instead? Would `export const COLUMN_TYPES = [ ... ] as const;` suit you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript array to string literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type)

Answer (score 2):

you can have enum instead of constant array like this and you can use it as type like this

```
export enum COLUMN_TYPES {
  integer,
  string,
  boolean,
  datetime,
  image,
  images,
  text,
  auth_key,
  enum_type
}


var types: COLUMN_TYPES[] = [COLUMN_TYPES.auth_key, COLUMN_TYPES.boolean, /** ............. **/ ];
```

**Example:** [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIHkAyBVAWQDkB9AFQE0AFAUQGU4BvAKDjgEtEZgBzYKADSs4AZxhROPIWwBGECABtgAQ0TS4AE2XcY7VMHV7lfQ6mPAR67iBjrlyGAAsSAa2ABPdUjQkY7sMDMAL7MoQBuylBwfmAiAFyYuISklLR0ANoAunAAvHDp2PjE5NT0AHT2Tq4eAolFKaV0ZXKKKmpwAPQAVF1wZf0DgwNwPR1wmQDcoQDGEIgirWUKEDwAFDEiAJQTQA)

**Updated Answer for CRice**

for example, you can define the statuses as enums like this

```
export enum ItemStatus {
  REJECTED = 2,
  REMOVED = 4,
  APPROVED = 6,
  PROCESSED = 7,
  PAYABLE = 8,
  PARTIALLY_PAID = 9,
  PAID = 10,
}
```

so in your item model, you will use the enum as a type of status

```
export interface ItemModel {
   // .......
   status: ItemStatus
}
```

and in component, you can import the `ItemStatus` and use it for example in the condition

**Usage Example**

```
import { ItemStatus } from 'path';
```

```
if(item.status === ItemStatus.PAID) {

}
```

or

```
switch(item.status) {

  case ItemStatus.REJECTED:
  break;
  case ItemStatus.REMOVED:
  break;
  case ItemStatus.APPROVED:
  break;
  case ItemStatus.PROCESSED:
  break;
  case ItemStatus.PAYABLE:
  break;
  case ItemStatus.PARTIALLY_PAID:
  break;
  case ItemStatus.PAID:
  break;

}
```

Comment: Good answer though fwiw I don't much like enums in typescript. Consider adding the alternative approach outlined in zerkms comment: use the `as const` modifier on the array and continue to use string literals instead of an enum.

Comment: @CRice I just improvised, I didn't use this before. Yes, I see it, let me test one more time.

Comment: @CRice the good things of the enums are that there will make your code more readable. for example, you can use the enums for the statuses, types and etc.

Comment: @CRice I have updated the asnwer with the usage example