# Typescript: Generate Type from Object keys and Array string values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm looking to generate a type from an Object's keys, and values of arrays of strings. The type needs to represent all the possible strings, i.e.

```
const Actions = {
  foo: ['bar', 'baz'],
}

# type generated from Actions to equal:
type ActionsType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'
```

I need to retain `Actions` as it's to be passed to a method, therefore:

```
const Actions = {
  foo: ['bar', 'baz'],
} as const


type ActionsType = keyof typeof Actions | typeof Actions[keyof typeof Actions][number]
```

whilst generating the type correctly didn't allow me to pass `Actions` to a method expecting `Record<string, string[]>` as the keys and values became readonly.

How can I generate the required type whilst still being able to use `Actions` as a non-readonly Object?

Comment: What you have done will work, but you need to use a const assertion on your array.. eg.. `foo: ['bar', 'baz'] as const`, otherwise typescript will see the array as been dynamic.

Comment: @Keith, unfortunately, the method the object is passed to expects a mutable `string[]` therefore setting `as const` on the object, or the individual arrays generates the following error: "The type 'readonly ["bar", "baz"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'"

Comment: Seems like you can use the "older" approach to generate types based on an array by using a function helper: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUxgXhgHgCo1QA8pUwATCGaAJwEswBzAbQF0A+ACgDoeBDahhABcMXAEpMbGP0EBuAFDzQkWAEFgUWuEpYA3vJgwAZiBAiEKVBwDkAI37WANDDu8AXtbGP5AX2mVlaAV5KABPRHR1TW1ccPQsAGtUUJAjODjUmCitSBgAH3SIzOztJiSUtLCitJLIFiYweABbW1RqFkV5I3gwDRzjUw4ZEQAlVFBqMmwaegZnGcZWNgldH0UTEA5aiDFgwNhePvARbdiIzBd7amtZIA). [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061487/863110)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to revert `readonly`ness of [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) / `as const`:

```
type Mutable<T> = {-readonly [K in keyof T]: Mutable<T[K]>}
```

The following will compile with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and adequate type safety:

```
type T1 = Mutable<typeof Actions> // { foo: ["bar", "baz"]; }

function foo(a: Record<string, string[]>) {}
foo(Actions as Mutable<typeof Actions>) // works
```

Be aware, that `Actions` object might be mutated inside `foo`, so you better treat it as mutable in the containing module as well. A cleaner alternative would be  to change `foo` signature to receive `readonly` arrays:

```
function foo2(a: Record<string, readonly string[]>) {}
foo2(Actions) // works without type assertion
```

[Code demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAgsKBLcEYF4YG8BQMYBmIIAXDANoDkARgIYBOlANDDbQF6UC6TOAvjFppQkWDhxQAngAcApvEQpIAFRnzMAa1mSQBGFLm6FyVDAA++tUYQnI5LTr0HZ1xai7kwAVwC21WfRc4gReYG5ghMQAFLRkAEqyoPQAJgA80PRIYADmLBlZ2eRcAHwAlNh8wdE2ShDlAPT1MAH0IPQ4RCBRNaZCMACyXlC01AA2sqnOrrYQZTCNMADubRoQ4s4DQyPjqcrFGNgAtPSytMngo5IUANIwWTAORspcZIPDYxPK5NcllRJqMGUAEYDm9thMpnoepB9gssJFSBQAER0ehIlgojhIrgAbhgfw6oXCCIATDF4ok2ml8jkWCczhcrjTCiVylhKp0ydC6kA)

Comment: thanks for your help with this. It led to a follow on question, which if you could provide any help on would be awesome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876213/typescript-generate-a-type-of-string-literals-from-an-objects-keys-and-values-r