# How can I generate a type of string literals from an objects keys and values returned by a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a type from a readonly object, i.e.

```
const Actions = {

  'user.crud': ['user.create', 'user.read', 'user.update', 'user.delete'],

} as const

type ActionsType = keyof typeof Actions | typeof Actions[keyof typeof Actions][number]
```

The above works nicely and sets up the type `ActionsType` to the string literals ('user.crud', 'user.create', etc..).

However, the `Actions` object above is very simplistic, instead, I really need to generate the Actions via functions. When I port the above over to being generated by a function, i.e.

```
// set up a function to generate all actions for the passed role
function getActions (role: string): Record<string, string[]> {

    return {
        [`${role}.crud`]: [`${role}.create`, `${role}.read`, `${role}.update`, `${role}.delete`],
    }

}

// generate the Actions from a function
const ActionsFromFunction = {

  ...getActions('user'),

} as const

// set up the Actions from a readonly object with values generated by getActions()
type ActionsFromFunctionType = keyof typeof ActionsFromFunction | typeof ActionsFromFunction[keyof typeof ActionsFromFunction][number]
```

the type `ActionsFromFunctionType` is no longer set to the string literals. Instead it is set to: `string | number` and in turn type tests fail as any string is accepted.

I've put together a demo of the above:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/PTAEGcFMBdQVwA6gIagGZwHYGNoEsB7TUaA0Ac0k0gCdlpIUAbJlXQzcdAmkgC0YJk4KABNQNAk0gBYAFAYc%20IhRgBBdkS4AKSdIBcEaDTyZyASkMAlSNh6iAPOGOnyAGiMmzAbQC6APlAAb3l5UHCJGDgaYhC5CITQbwADABIgvUgAXwA6bBo4UWTfQxT0zNz8yHpIZI80jKlsnJpqovryptzEURq60AaKnNFIaQZitzCIrNC5GblZ4AAqCBh4JGgBUA1lThR4KF5sZGJoZABrRiXgRbBKajoGfkYdji40SQBbfcVNTHk7JxYK8tAAxL6grB-UAAXmCs3COSRlGgIM42gA5HBDhjzJMFnMUFxAc5bqAAO4mJ7IFjbP5ccl4TamZ6gAgAIwAVrZoACtMD6bD4QTwljDnkCqIMaUxbQJdUGBiPLKaC02krQCqcj0ahqtSMxpAMb58fIskTQCTeQT5MtVrBEKzoABPBCQLikEju2DIcjIUzOUDXMlQB0bLZo95ffatZCiIhMZ1srk8ilMvigABuNLg7tUDxq4nZSZRke05nkLrddN24HBBE%20kKUHAAKq7GHDLs6CGgSO2ezW3vXG1DdqAAD59t0DyPDpt-bxdgdVyAz%20lz0ccXzeTBwT7s2i%20ENrR2bF6Cj4NlDEWPxzCJ5Pc3CV9uDrRt6udyDd3srte1icp1XXtI0Xb9l37ED6W3Xd90PWZbRWdk4DwJhxFaOwaFELhsVcJ12y4ZB2QITMrhuAkrVAKwACE1AAYUvEdmyIaxbHsBxZwhTciA-SAPGIpoTkCOE4nCNACAIQxjFzDwQAgPgCDgNDQFoSReGEbgyDwLhMAIH1iGQaEVymLV8kKaV0BpKB8XmPkgSo2i6NYzDHEjXj%20Ik6QhKFUTNKkgo%20NAOTMIw6AH1UnhwBM7E5TMqVDDQKy%20LNeQgA)

Is there a way of generating the `Actions` object via a function, whilst still maintaining the string literals within the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is only achievable through typescript [Template literal types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types). **They are not supported in typescript 4.0**, but will be available in 4.1 version.

This is how you could do it with typescript 4.1

```
type CrudOperations<ROLE extends string> = [`${ROLE}.create`, `${ROLE}.read`, `${ROLE}.update`, `${ROLE}.delete`];

type GetActionsResult<ROLE extends string> = string extends ROLE // check if we can infer type
  ? { [k: string]: string[] } // if type is not inferable
  : { [K in `${ROLE}.crud`]: CrudOperations<ROLE> };

function getActions<ROLE extends string>(role: ROLE): GetActionsResult<ROLE> {
    return {
      [`${role}.crud`]: [`${role}.create`, `${role}.read`, `${role}.update`, `${role}.delete`]
    } as GetActionsResult<ROLE>;
}

// falls back to { string: string[] } structure
const actions = getActions('admin' as string);

// generate the Actions from a function
const ActionsFromFunction = {
  ...getActions('user'),
  ...getActions('orders'),
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgTgVwCYHlJwIbAJYHsB2AzgDwBKKAMgKJQQAewE+ShUhwc2+A5gHxQBeKAG0ABgBIA3uWoBfAHQBjOBCwRRAGigTplKgpUYkm7VJn75CMEjUmd5hUggAbCI1EBdANwBYAFD+oJBQAOJuAIKKOASEpBCECM7AZHq0DEwsbBxcfIJZnDxpjMys5lAA9OVQigAWEIoA1lDYAGZQAO7Qihj4zfgtEHBQQRD+UFAA-FCSIg0AXPk5HgvsBdzCHlCyFVWtw+DQ2Kz4uMB9A5gARq5jUAszwgDSfaa6ckqIxsuwn2iDWHgiClqPxZL4An4Wgh8FFAVBuBFYTFgTR6MVMqscrwABRwXCuBbmACUCzCwEi0SIcQSSRR-Ekt3GKmACDgvQZfnGXJEOjxrgUymQngWYikfIgAsM7i0vPxEvkhmMMrFcoUVhs0te4scLjc6g8jK2UAwrDJFMBsXiiWS5l44Nk-n8lSgLQwzmcrEuGEaw1w00WPBW2R4GyNqwQUVZoz8ihiZ29lNYQgR5KRRGxAHIjABbLgZ42sTE8Ingp1VBH4f6MYZ1KDmmIuvHZ40u6Fp-yxohnetEABiTd7bcpeQ543k45TPcImYQhEGGaJGlu4-kk7T04zuDgTjghAXS78siAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can also write `getActions` without explicit types by inference:

```
function getActions<K extends string>(role: K) {
  const actions = {
    [`${role}.crud`]: [`${role}.create`, `${role}.read`, `${role}.update`,
    `${role}.delete`],
  } as const
  return actions as Record<K,typeof actions[K]>
}
```

Test it:

```
const ActionsFromFunction = {
  ...getActions('user'),
} 
// { user: readonly ["user.create", "user.read", "user.update", "user.delete"];}

const ActionsFromFunction2 = {
  ...getActions('user' as string),
} 
// { [x: string]: readonly [`${string}.create`, ..., `${string}.delete`]; }

type ActionsFromFunctionType =
  | keyof typeof ActionsFromFunction
  | typeof ActionsFromFunction[keyof typeof ActionsFromFunction][number]
// "user" | "user.create" | "user.read" | "user.update" | "user.delete"
```

Note, that `getActions` won't be accurate, if your `role` has a union `string` type:

```
const ActionsFromFunction3 = {
  ...getActions('user' as 'user' | 'admin'),
} // { user: ...; admin: ...; }
```

You might write `getActions` as [distributed conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), if needed:

```
return actions as K extends any ? Record<K,typeof actions[K]> : never
```

```
const ActionsFromFunction3 = {
  ...getActions('user' as 'user' | 'admin'),
}
/* 
| { user: readonly ["user.create", "user.read", "user.update", "user.delete"];} 
| { admin: readonly ["admin.create", "admin.read", "admin.update", "admin.delete"]; } 
*/
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201112#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQILXmAzgHgGlFUAPKVMAE10VygCcYxkA+ACgbgBtUAuRIQCUiAN4BYAFCJEEBPUQBDbPMQBeMVJkyA2gAMAJKK68AvgDoIDEFT0BdAfqMnUFq6kUU9AGkSHjPK7mDB62vv4uFiAADlSeqD5a2hGBFlSovF523kmmSrRyeFBJIVAgDEjKsKqKtMRkFNS0imAAnogA-IgASqhyDFRE3lCt0ahwwEoqeDqEdqyIAmCoAG6oDFKmUlKFCljVeABiXAC2h+DT6prSiOZ3aJjTuOwA5CC46y9COZJbkgD0-xkokQ73WAhCiioCG47R0ACIwQxLJCKPDfIiPsjIVR0YhMetzDE4miMUjzOlMqh4XYANyIP47eRQRD7HC4Y5wM4XA4AJiuEhud3MDzZ8leSJe+TojGYyG+mykgLEiB0pAE9CYLAciBxMLh-k1crcqISvmF4SMRpYaQy6ASdIZ20kIzGrKenO5kAOABVRqh1EkAD6IADWqFaE0QrvGkzFR1O529OGD0f9UfjHMTPJwOnDkcmMYzHuzyYQdh0YBAJwARus7EqgQSGPDECHmyiPGi2-jyTjW+3ycT4gPe1iKXa0c7dizM56k9MAMwCpLC0VPCVYqW1RBvLc9l5Qk7ML4-P7-ABUiCkIZBSIhoX1qo77hHZPH-ffhOHpLHhMp9o0rSeQ3iqR7MA+UJPgi4FgJ2b74rBwShHi8JIT+1IYkhAFoo6IGSBe-xAA)

Comment: like that this is pretty clean, am I right in thinking this is something for future as it doesn't seem to work outside the nightly 4.2 builds?

Comment: This is already possible with upcoming TS 4.1 (today/tomorrow release?). You currently need to use the Nightly Playground, as TS 4.1 beta didn't include some narrowing features for string literals yet. I just tested locally with TS 4.1 RC - .