# How to get the value of keys from an array of objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the array:

```
const studyTypes = [
   {
     value: "ENG",
     label: "ENG-RU",
   },
   {
     value: "RU",
     label: "RU-ENG",
   },
];
```

And the state:

```
const [typeStudy, setTypeStudy] = React.useState<string>("ENG");
```

How can I specify in typescript that my `typeStudy` can only take one of the `value` from the `studyTypes` array instead of a `<string>`? In this case the `typeStudy` can be  either "ENG" or "RU".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript array to string literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could declare studyTypes as a const, it should be like this:

```
const studyTypes = [
   {
     value: "ENG",
     label: "ENG-RU",
   },
   {
     value: "RU",
     label: "RU-ENG",
   },
] as const; // as const is important for this step

type Value = typeof studyTypes[number]['value'];


const testValue: Value = "PQR" // This will throw a type error.
```

This will only work with Typescript v3.4 or greater.

Here's an example from my VSCode checking for lint errors:
[image: dynamic types]

Comment: Yes. It works. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can define a new type as literal type.

```
type TypeStudy = "ENG" | "RU";
```

and then

```
React.useState<TypeStudy>
```