# Typescript: generic object with dynamic number of keys and values

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics

Currently, my code looks like this:

```js
interface TestInterface<T extends string> {
    data: {
        [key in T]: () => void;
    }
}

const testCommand: TestInterface<"fun1"> = {
    data: {
        fun1: () => {
            // do something
        },
    }
};

testCommand.data.fun1();
```

I pass a `string` (in this example "fun1") as a generic to the `testCommand` function. In the `data` object, I can access this string/function "fun1".

My Question: Can I pass an array of strings as a generic to have a custom amount of functions in the `data` object (Maybe convert the `data` obj to an array)?

Example:

```js
const testCommand: TestInterface<["fun1", "fun2", "fun3"]> = {
    data: {
        fun1: () => {
            // do something
        },
        fun2: () => {
            // do something
        },
        fun3: () => {
            // do something
        },
    }
};
```

or:

```js
const testCommand: TestInterface<["fun1", "fun2", "fun3"]> = {
    data: [
        { name: "fun1", exec: () => {} },
        { name: "fun2", exec: () => {} },
        { name: "fun3", exec: () => {} },
    ]
};
```

Comment: Note that what you are calling `key` is a generic *type* parameter, not a key name/identifier. As such, it is conventional to use UpperPascalCase like `Key`, or even more conventionally, a single uppercase later like `K`.  It is not the same as the `key` in  `{[key: string]: () => void`, where `key` is a dummy key identifier whose type is `string`.  In a mapped type of the form `{[K in X]: () => void}`, `K` is the *type* (not the *name*) of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an array, you can just pass in a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) you want to support; the resulting [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) will contain all of the keys:

```
const testCommand: TestInterface<"fun1" | "fun2" | "fun3"> = {
    data: {
        fun1: () => {
            // do something
        },
        fun2: () => {
            // do something
        },
        fun3: () => {
            // do something
        },
    }
};
```

Indeed, this is very much like using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), where you pass in a union of key types for `K` and a value type for `V`, and get a type with properties of type `V` at all keys in `K`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gJLmvJAHlWQgA9IQATDZLKUAcwD5kBvAKGW+SrjDgAudlx5iA2gGsIAT2Sg0AXWEAKAJTIAvKwBuAe2BUA3KO4BfDhY4I9ILMkhYAwnoC2ruNQCMw9FlyQsIgQhABEMACuIF6hrJoiYnwCwpxiYpHRqhraCWl5APT5vHp0bhBgABZMpmlmADQ1FmYmHNa29o5gLu6eVL6YOHhBROFRMcgAPsijIABMoZPTGQDMsVq53ElCG2kZPsjqWqypeWmFxaWu5VUgjDVi9fc8GbNZRzunyOdUJRhlldVPo9Pis3jkTp9uN9fv8bncgQ0HpYTEA)

Comment: Thanks! You can also convert an array to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061487/10433038