# typescript: how to infer array of a union instead of union of arrays

Tags: typescript

let's say we have a function `toArray` that takes an argument and returns it as is if it is an array and if not returns an array with the argument value:

```
// function that takes a value and returns the value if it is of type array and if not returns the value in an array
export const toArray = <T>(value: T | T[]): T extends undefined ? [] : Array<T> => {
  if (typeof value === "undefined") return [] as any;
  return (Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]) as any;
};
```

this function works fine as long as the type of the arguments is not union:

```
number => number[]
number[] => number[]
```

for unions I got not the expected result:

```
// wanted
'a'|'b' => ('a'|'b')[]

// currently
'a'|'b' => 'a'[] | 'b'[]
```

How do I tell typescript to infer array of union instead of union of arrays?

Comment: Your return statements have `as any`, so does it really matter what type you get? The value that's passed as a generic is either a, or b. It's not interpreted as "union  type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) says :

> To avoid that behavior (distributivity), you can surround each side of the extends keyword with square brackets.

You should define the returned type of the function like this :

```
[T] extends [undefined] ? [] : Array<T>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Note that [TypeScript does not infer literal values from objects (including arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type). For that, you'll need to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on object literal input values. (See examples in the code below.)

You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with a [function overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to achieve your goal.

Here's an example demonstrating the details in your question:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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)

```ts
const intoArray: {
  (value?: undefined): unknown[];
  <T extends readonly unknown[]>(value: T): T[number][];
  <T>(value: T): T[];
} = (value?: unknown) => typeof value === "undefined" ? []
  : Array.isArray(value) ? [...value]
  : [value];

const result1 = intoArray();
    //^? const result1: unknown[]

const result2 = intoArray(undefined);
    //^? const result2: unknown[]

const result3 = intoArray('hello');
    //^? const result3: string[]

const result3Literal = intoArray('hello' as const);
    //^? const result3Literal: "hello"[]

const result4 = intoArray(['hello']);
    //^? const result4: string[]

const result4Literal = intoArray(['hello'] as const);
    //^? const result4Literal: "hello"[]

const result5 = intoArray(['a', 'b']);
    //^? const result5: string[]

const result5Literal = intoArray(['a', 'b'] as const);
    //^? const result5Literal: ("a" | "b")[]
```

---

I used a function expression above because that's what you showed in the question, but it's more common to use a declaration with the overload pattern (you'll find this in the overwhelming majority of examples online):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMU4EEBOmCGBPRACgDccAbEAUwH4AuRcAE0uBUsYEp7wBrMOAO5gA2gF0A3AChQkWAmSoM2fIgA8AFUSUAHlEphGAZ0SZKORgjIFe-IWIB8JclXrquidcLAgAtgCNKTFExKRloeCQUNCxcAg1HUgpKV3dPCWlwcPkopViiRKo6BjA+QTAORABvSUQTSigQTCQoPAAHSjhgRALKRABeAcQAIiYWNkYhxGpEMRraxHoY-AA6GEMlvCckiunhZf2e0Tna+mFDqQBfSUkIBEMoOsMQMigARn6FaOVNjil5xAA9ACAHrUa63MD3R7PKAAJg+OQ2hFGrDA7F+x0BILBNzuD1MTxeAGYEYokQByAAWlDIZDg5Ix-yBoPBeOhxIAMjA9LgyKSvrFCFSaXTyYgcMYIfdGfNmTipfjKISoAAWfm5fCEYTC2n00Qy2py1mQxXKlVcnnkdVI7XU3Xk0TiyV4g1Ylm4k3sqAAVmt3y15Jw5IANIhyX4Ha6jR6oQSYd6LYErX1PhrNtqg6Hww6nYgFVHsZIgA)

```ts
function intoArray (value?: undefined): unknown[];
function intoArray <T extends readonly unknown[]>(value: T): T[number][];
function intoArray <T>(value: T): T[];
function intoArray (value?: unknown) {
  return typeof value === "undefined" ? []
    : Array.isArray(value) ? [...value]
    : [value];
}
```