# How to convert existing array to TypeScript string literal type?

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript array to string literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type) asks and receives an answer regarding how to create a string literal upon array declaration. I am wondering if it is possible to create a string literal from an *already existing* array.

To take the same basic example:

```
const furniture = ['chair', 'table', 'lamp'];
type Furniture = 'chair' | 'table' | 'lamp';
```

the suggested known solution at declaration is:

```
const furniture = ['chair', 'table', 'lamp'] as const;
```

This locks the array to a `readonly`. Is it possible to just take the array and make a new item from it?

```
const furniture = ['chair', 'table', 'lamp'];
const furntureLiteral = furniture as const;

// Yields: "readonly [string[]]" typing.
// Wanted: "readonly ["chair", "table", "lamp"]" typing.
```

Or is it impossible due to static typing?

Comment: Yes, you are right - due to static typing array needs to be declared as const immideately, since it's impossible to know if it changed between the lines. With const array then you just use `(typeof furniture)[number]`.

Comment: you can also define each member as const
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVwE5gJZWQUxgXhgbQHJgALAQ1SUJjIhlEigBoZCoyAjAG02tvvDQWhLmQC2ABz50G0ALoBuALAAoKAE8J2AGLI0GJNjwatIOPD3osqmLZgB6ezAB6AflVA)

Comment: As you've shown if you don't add further metadata when the array's created it's `string[]`. You can't get back to more detail from that.

Comment: Is there any value in doing a workaround, of reversing the declarations order: `const furnitureLiteral = ['chair', 'table', 'lamp'] as const;
const furniture = [...furnitureLiteral];`

does `furniture` have any additional capacities?

Comment: You could do that but presumably you want `furniture` to be of type `string[]`, so you'd write something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbEYdN) maybe? Do you want to see that written up as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz this is great, nice addition with the specific `string[]` typing. Now the array has full funcionality. If you write it up as an answer I will accept it and close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `furniture` for two different purposes: remembering the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the values it's initialized with, but also holding arbitrary other strings in the future.  TypeScript doesn't really give you the flexibility to do both with a single variable.  The easiest way forward could be to have two variables, one for each purpose.

You can keep track of the initalizer via [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) which "locks" the resulting variable:

```
const initialFurniture = ['chair', 'table', 'lamp'] as const;
type InitialFurniture = typeof initialFurniture[number];
// type InitialFurniture = "chair" | "table" | "lamp"
```

And then copy that into a mutable string array that lets you do anything you want:

```
const furniture: string[] = [...initialFurniture];
furniture.push("futon");
furniture.push("hammock");
furniture.push("cupboard");
```

Now you've separated the concerns and the TypeScript compiler is satisfied also.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2AxArgJ0VXAUxgF4YBtAcmAAsU4dKAaGSqFAIzUOdbRQC2AB0oBdGCggxQkKAG4AsACgoATyHEAkvlSZc+IqRhqNIAGbwd6bHiRFyYLAI6EcoxUoD0n4+q1W9WwIcYjIAIlp6HDCYAB8YMPYuQhj4sP5hMOUZaBgzfTsQgC4YaBwEAHNycTJyADoGhCRdGwMQ92V8oKI6oSwIGgAKMPyocDCASg8utsJe-qGwugEBEGAAa0npguC5voHh4CwhDhAUHAATLeUgA)